# Check MSI installation status

Tags: c#, remote-access, windows-installer

I have a MSI file which I am copying to client machine using WMI Remote Connection. After Copying it to some location , I install it and update status as 'Installation Completed'. But the problem I face is the process of sending status completed is taking place so instantly after the code below that even if it fails the Status would be Completed.

```
inParams["CommandLine"] = "msiexec.exe /i " + @"""" + @"c:\windows\temp\" + tempFolderName + @"\Agent.msi" + @"""" + " " + String.Format("/q HEARTBEATSERVERIP={0} CONSOLESERVICEURL={1} HEARTBEATSERVERPORT={2} DOMAINACCOUNT={3} DOMAINACCOUNTPASSWORD={4}", this.heartbeatServerIp, this.consoleServiceUrl, this.heartbeatServerPort, this.userName, this.password);
```

The above line initiates the installation process and the below code determines how I process the whole thing

```
File.WriteAllText(remoteCopy, cmdFileBuilder.ToString());

Process scriptProc = new Process();

scriptProc.StartInfo.FileName = "cscript";

scriptProc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = programDataPath; //<---very important exe location
scriptProc.StartInfo.Arguments = "//B //Nologo remotecopy.vbs";

scriptProc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; //prevent console window from popping up
scriptProc.Start();
scriptProc.WaitForExit(); // <-- Optional if you want program running until your script exit
scriptProc.Close();

var agentMsiFileName = "\\" + ipAddress + @"\admin$\Temp\" + tempFolderName + @"\Agent.msi";

//remote copy completed...

//remote copy completed...
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();

///Start remote execution
///
try
{
    var wmiProcess = new ManagementClass(scope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), new ObjectGetOptions());
    ManagementBaseObject inParams = wmiProcess.GetMethodParameters("Create");
    inParams["CommandLine"] = "msiexec.exe /i " + @"""" + @"c:\windows\temp\" + tempFolderName + @"\Agent.msi" + @"""" + " " + String.Format("/q HEARTBEATSERVERIP={0} CONSOLESERVICEURL={1} HEARTBEATSERVERPORT={2} DOMAINACCOUNT={3} DOMAINACCOUNTPASSWORD={4}", this.heartbeatServerIp, this.consoleServiceUrl, this.heartbeatServerPort, this.userName, this.password);
    ManagementBaseObject outParams = wmiProcess.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
    LogUtilities.Info("Creation of the process returned: " + outParams["returnValue"]);
    LogUtilities.Info("Process ID: " + outParams["processId"]);
    LogUtilities.Info("Installation completed for : " + discoveredMachineId + " " + ipAddress);

    SendAgentStatus(discoveredMachineId, "Completed"); //Installation Completed
```

I know that we can check for the [status codes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/304888) of installer which I used in the code and it returns '0' instantly without waiting for the completion, its for creation of the process completion.

```
ManagementBaseObject outParams = wmiProcess.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
LogUtilities.Info("Creation of the process returned: " + outParams["returnValue"]);
```

Also I could cross-check the registry with

```
var checkKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{Product-code}");
```

but it takes atleast 1-2 minutes or even more than that depending on the system configurations. So, is there a way we can figure this out to perfection?

**I want to wait till the installation gets complete and then send the status Completed.**